# how could I place a conditional for next action

Tags: flutter, firebase, if-statement, firebase-authentication

I would like to condition the sign out action depending If I have already or not sign in. I just tried with an "If" before everything but it show a "expected identifier" and "expected )". I would like to learn abut this part

I tried with an "If" conditional before PopUp menu.

```
         appBar: AppBar(

            title: Text("Categoria"),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(150, 255, 0, 0),


                actions: [
                  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "usu", password: "cla")==true){
                    PopupMenuButton(

                      onSelected: (Menu item) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (item == Menu.logout) {
                            FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Login()));
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      <PopupMenuEntry<Menu>>[
                        PopupMenuItem(value: Menu.logout,
                            child: Text("Cerrar sesión")
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  }
                ],
```

[Here is the upgrated code after ur advices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN6RS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current auth state:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for ur support. Is there any way to hide the sign out option If some one hasnt already sign in?

Comment: you can set the state if the user is null and sign out button will be null

Answer (score 0):

put the above the line of PopupMenuButton

```
           title: Text("Categoria"),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(150, 255, 0, 0),


                
                actions: [
                if (FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "usu" password: "cla"))
                PopupMenuButton(

                onSelected: (Menu item) {
                setState(() {
                if (item == Menu.logout) {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Login()));
                }
                });
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                <PopupMenuEntry<Menu>>[
                PopupMenuItem(value: Menu.logout,
                child: Text("Cerrar sesión")
                )
                ],
                )

                ],
                
          ),
```

you can use if clause only like that after return part:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    if(condition == true) // or you just can write condition
    Text('true')
  ]
)
```

or you can use ? and :

```
return Container(
  child: 
  condition == true // or you just can write condition
  ? Text('true')
  : Text('false')
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur support. I tried like that but it shows an error. Not sure how to solve it, I researched but not useful info for it. It is "the element type popupmenubutton<menu> cant be assigned to the list type widget".  I used also { } after If() condition

Comment: can you update the code? I can't see 'popupmenubutton<menu>' part from your current code

Comment: Just Done. I updated the ScreenShot showing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: first of all Menu.logout is not a Menu type, because Menu itself can be a Menu type but its subobject is not. and from the screenshot you just need to remove {} from the if clause as I explained